# Chrome memory leak or is my type of programming defective?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, google-chrome, memory-leaks

I currently working on a website which runs without any problems, but in Chrome i noticed huge memory usage! I start a new tab and opening my site, the memory usage starts with 40MB (i use the chrome task manager for detecting the memory usage) so all sounds normally. Now i just reload the site and the memory increases significantly. By just clicking around on the website background or anywhere where no events are binded or any functions it is also possible to increase the memory a little bit (really slowly < 10 MB). Now i have for example images on my page which are thumbnails and if you hover over them you have the possibility to enlarge them. The image ratio of the original image is calculated and the source of this one is used. Yeah you know what i mean absolutely normal stuff, but this image enlarging is a huge memory increaser - much worse than reloading the site.
So i thought about it for a long, i searched for possible memory leaks in my javascript part and so on but i didn't find anything which could be a problem. Maybe because i do not know it better! I am not really experienced at this. Okay afterwards i tested my site also in the latest version of Firefox as well as in Internet Explorer. In the following picture you can see the results, i also added the version of the browsers so you can see which one i used:[image: Memory usage in different Browsers]
I repeated all memory increasing steps in all browsers at the same way, for my measurement. As you can see Firefox is really memory friendly, only 17.22 MB at all! Internet Explorer is also okay with 77.6 MB, but Chrome is a disaster - using near to 460 MB RAM :-(.

For my bad eg. YouTube needs in Chrome only 130-150 MB and has not this memory problems... . So my question is which problem is this? I mean in all other Browsers it works fine except Chrome (I think Opera and Safari will have the same problems, because they are based on webkit (not tested) ).

Is there anything which i could improve or what i should note while programming websites for Chrome to avoid such memory problems? I would be really thankfull if anyone, who is more experienced than me (in this part of web development), is able to give me some advices to avoid memory leaks or memory problems in Chrome!

## Edit (29.06.2015): I already tried to disable the hardware acceleration in Chrome, but this doesn't change anything - still the same memory problems!

Comment: This kind of issues usually has relation with javascript timeouts and loops or intervals. Did you check for this kind of code? It could be the cause.

Comment: Can't say anything about your type of programming without seeing your code, however Chrome just drains memory anyway. For instance each chrome tab is a whole new process which adds quite a lot overhead. It trades RAM for speed. I doubt that it's an issue in your code (the other browser would be affected too, if that was the case). You could try deleting your browsers cache.

Comment: @kmsdev i have checked already for setTimeout functions, loops with no end, intervals and so on but there is nothing which looks like it causing this problem and if there were a infinity loop it would also affect other browsers like Firefox.

Comment: @Sebastian Nette i tried to delete the browser chache but it doesn't change anything :-(. Still huge memory usage.

Comment: I meant about loops with timeouts OR intervals. I mean, if you have some intervals which never stop, it could be the cause. It's true that in other browsers the ram should be affected too but it's also true that chrome likes to eat ram (more than other browsers). I suggest you to update your question with your javascript code or, if it's possible, create a jsFiddle.

Comment: @kmsdev the problem is my whole site, in case of that i do not know what the huge memory usage cause i can not create a jsfiddle with the part of my javascript... . Also i do not really want to post a link to my site, because i am still in development and so i do not want to make the site public... . How can a interval never stops? Only if i use it recursive or in a loop, right? Because this i already checked and no there is nothing, which act like this. Do you have any other general suggestions?

Comment: To answer *"How can a interval never stops?"*.. It happens if there isn't a `clearInterval()` method which stops it. It's really hard to solve without look the code, I have no more ideas or suggestions.

Comment: @kmsdev can you give me an email or any other contact possibility? I would send you the link to my site.

Comment: I am sorry, I would, but if you need someone to analyse your code, out of SO, it will have a cost. I have no problem to let my help and my knowledge to somebody, but publicly. If we pass to something private I can't help you, out of SO, for free. I hope you understand it.

Comment: @kmsdev it is okay, i will go on with the development of my site and after i finished my work and released it - it will be public. So at this time i will reply on this, but it will take a long time from now on till the site is ready to publish... . So i hope i can fix it by my own till then.

Comment: if anyone still has general advices in avoiding memory leaks in chrome (because in other browsers it seems that all work like it should) - i would be thankful for each of them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest Build of Chrome fixed the memory leak problem completely!

=> Version 45.0.2453.0 dev-m

I really hope that this version comes stable as soon as possible or at least for the day where i release/publish my site^^.

It seems as it was a Chrome (i think Opera and other browser which are based on webkit have/had also the problem) only (memory leak) bug.